# How to get filename with a replaced extension from find command

Tags: command-line, find, xargs

[dextract](https://github.com/thegenemyers/DEXTRACTOR) is a tool which convert files. The normal usage is `dextract -q test.h5 > test.fastq`. How is it possible to combine it with find command e.g. `find All_RawData/Each_Cell_Raw/ -name "*.bax.h5" | xargs -I {} dextract -q {} >` How to get the file name after `>` from `find` command with `fastq` extension rather `h5` extension?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321753/135943 which gives the *best* way to call a command on each file found by `find`.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
find All_RawData/Each_Cell_Raw -name '*.bax.h5' -exec sh -c 'for f do dextract -q "$f" > "${f%.h5}.fastq"; done' find-sh {} +
```

With some line breaks for easier reading:

```
find All_RawData/Each_Cell_Raw -name '*.bax.h5' -exec sh -c '
  for f
    do dextract -q "$f" > "${f%.h5}.fastq"
  done' find-sh {} +
```

For explanation and rationale, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321753/135943.